# setParams not working in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux, react-navigation

I am using react-native with redux. I am trying to update current screen's params so that they can be accessed in a component used in top-bar but parameter is not getting set. 
My code is following:

Screen Route:

```
AlertNameForm: {
    screen: AlertNameForm,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => CancelAndDone(navigation)
  }
```

Component Screen: In componentDidMount I am setting parameter.

```
class AlertNameForm {
    ..........
    componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({onDonePress: this.onDonePress})
    }

    onDonePress: () => {
      // want to access this function in top-bar buttons.
    }
}
```

Following is further components:

```
export const CancelAndDone = (navigation) => ({
    headerLeft: <ButtonCancel navigation={navigation} />,
    headerRight: <ButtonDone navigation={navigation} />
})

const ButtonDone = withTheme(({navigation, theme: { tertiaryColor } }) => (
  <Button color={tertiaryColor} title="Done" onPress={() => {
      if (navigation.state.params && navigation.state.params.onDonePress) {
        navigation.state.params.onDonePress()
      }
      else {
        navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.back())
      }
    }} />
))
```

But in ButtonDone component I am not able to access function **onDonePress**
Is there any other way to setParams for current screen in react-native.

Comment: do you means you want to access onDonePress inside navigationOptions ? can you create a jsfiddle for much clear code.

Answer (score 0):

You should reference `navigation.state.params`using `this.props` since navigation should be passed as a prop to that component.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the function within the target component as follows:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
   const { navigation } = this.props
     navigation.setParams({
        onDonePress: () => this.myFunction(),
     })
}

myFunction = () => { /*body function*/ }
```

In your header or footer component call:

`navigation.state.params.onDonePress` or `route.params.onDonePress` if you using React Navigation v5.